# JQuery Window is not persisting

Tags: jquery

I am novice to jQuery and looking for your help.

I have code something like below -

```
var flag = true;
 items = $.extend(items, items,
                {

                    addItem: {
                        label: 'Create new ' + nodeObject.ChildType,
                        action: function () {
                            var form = $('#lowerpanel form');
                            if (!validateForm(form)) {
                                return;
                            }
var hasChanges = parseBoolean($('#lowerpanel #ProcessChanges').val());
 if (hasChanges) {                                    
 flag = false;
selectPopup($('#lowerpanel .guid').val(), 'Update', nodeObject.ChildType, nodeObject.NodeId, fnOnWarningOk1, parameters);
}
selectPopup(null, 'create', nodeObject.ChildType, nodeObject.NodeId);
promptStepType(node);
}
flag = true;
}
}
});
```

When `hasChanges` flag is true, it opens `selectPopup` window with Update flag, there I select some records and click OK button.

Immediately after that I want to open `selectPopup` window with Create flag,and later call `promptStepType` method which will open new window on top of `selectPopup` window. Then I will first select record from `promptStepType`  window and `onclick` of Ok button it will allow me to selet record on `selectPopup` window.

What is happening is `selectPopup` window with Update flag opens but disappears immediately that I cannot even see it on screen (When I put debugger I was able to see that window) and it open `selectPopup` window with Create flag and then open p`romptStepType` window on top of it.

I want to:

1. `selectPopup` window with update flag
2. `selectPopup` window with create flag
3. promptStepType

If I write Return false after statement -

```
selectPopup($('#lowerpanel .guid').val(), 'Update', nodeObject.ChildType, nodeObject.NodeId, fnOnWarningOk1, parameters);
```

It will allow me to select record but then it wont show me other two windows.

Please help me improve this code so that I will be able to select records on all 3 windows.